# CSS not loading on Wordpress / Google App Engine

Tags: css, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am having trouble loading some css/js from wp-content, wp-includes on a Wordpress site I have hosted on Google App Engine.

[image: web console]

I am using the same app.yaml that is suggested on [Google App Engine's Wordpress article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress). I also tweaked the rules to see if they can accommodate the ver=.*, but no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define static folder in app.yaml file

In my case I have a static folder which contains all js, css and images.

Here is my folder structure

```
static
 - css
 - img
 - js
```

Here is my app.yaml file code spinet

```
- url: /(img|css|js|images|avatars|font|partials|json)/(.*)
  static_files: static/\1/\2
  upload: static/(img|css|js|images|avatars|font)/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bad rule I added in the end...

I added

url: /blog/(.+)?/?
-  script: \1/index.php

Removed, now it works fine.